# C - sockets, separating data and http header?

Tags: c, sockets, http, client-server

I am trying to simulate client/server communication to send and receive files using sockets and http requests.

The client sends an http request to the server saying that they want to download a simple .txt file and the server sends the file data back to the client with an http response header.

However, the data written into the received text file also contains the http header information which it shouldn't.

How do I effectively separate the http header from the actual data?

Here's what the code looks like:

**Server:**

```
//receives an http header request from client saying they want to download a .txt file

bzero(buffer, 256);

sprintf(buffer, "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n Date:%s\r\n Content-Type:%s\r\n Content-Length:%s\r\n\r\n", time, content, length);

data = write(incoming_socket, buffer, strlen(buffer)); // first sends an http response header

bzero(buffer, 256);

int data;

while((data = fread(buffer, sizeof(char), 256, fs)) > 0){

    if(send(cli_socket, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0) < 0){ // sends the actual file data to client in this while cycle 

        perror("ERROR: Could not send file.");
        break;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (block_size < 256){

        if (ferror(fs)){

            perror("ERROR: Failed while sending data.");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        bzero(buffer, 256);

        break;
    }

    bzero(buffer, 256);
}
```

**Client:**

```
bzero(buffer, 256);

data = read(client_socket, buffer, 256); // first receive the http header response 

bzero(buffer, 256);

while (1){

    data = recv(client_socket, buffer, 256, 0); // receive data

    fwrite(buffer, sizeof(char), data, fr); // write data into the file 

    bzero(buffer, 256);

    if (data == 0 || data < 256){

        fclose(fr);
        break;
    }

    if(data< 0){

        printf("failed while copyng file!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

However, this fills the .txt file with the http response as well, not just the data.

Now, I know that I should probably look for /r/n/r/n in the header response in order to separate the header and write just the actual data but, if someone could show me the best way to do this in my example with my particular buffer, I'd be very grateful!

Comment: No. You should look for `\r\n\r\n`.

Comment: In the server, your read-send loop is flawed. You read up to 256 bytes from the files, leaving no space for a string terminator. Then you use `strlen` to get the length if the data you just read, and that can lead to *undefined behavior* if the data you just read filled the whole buffer. Either read `255` bytes from the file, or use `data` as the length to send.

Comment: Yes I know I should look for \r\n\r\n, but what would be the best way to do this in my example? And thanks, I corrected that to 255.

Comment: Oh and the read-send loop is even more flawed if you you read a binary file, as that might contain zero bytes which is just what the string terminator happens to be. In that case you will not send the complete file, only small partial chunks of it.

Comment: You've made almost every possible mistake. You're nowhere close to how to do any of this correctly. I would strongly urge you to look at working HTTP/1.1 client and server code to gain an understanding of the right to do all of this stuff. (You may be able to get it to appear to work under some conditions by luck, but you'll be doing damage to your ability to understand how to write code that is guaranteed to work.)

Comment: Guys please, I asked a simple question. How do I separate the header from the data. If you know the answer I'd be very glad if you could give it to me instead of referring me to literature.

Comment: @Daeto When someone asks how to start a jackhammer so they can get the demons out of their grandmother's head, you don't tell them how to start a jackhammer! If you're trying to implement HTTP 1.1, you have to go through the specification and implement every relevant "must". For example, chunked encoding is a must. Where's your code for that? Do you really want to write code for that?

Comment: Also make sure you protect your system from requests like `/../../topSecret.txt`.

Comment: *every time you call `strlen()` or `bzero()`, God kills a kitten*

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, you've chosen a *very* compelex protocol to implement. Your only choice is to read the documentation for HTTP version 1.1 and follow the specification precisely. The documentation will tell you how to identify the end of the header. Note that you *must* support chunked encoding. It is required for HTTP 1.1 compliance.

But you've really chosen an H-bomb to kill an ant here. HTTP 1.1 is a complex, high-performance protocol and a terrible choice for just messing around transferring a file.

A few more mistakes:

```
if(send(cli_socket, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0) < 0){ // sends the actual file data to client in this while cycle
```

The `strlen` function is only for C-style strings, not arbitrary data. The `recv` function returns the number of bytes read for a reason.

```
data = recv(client_socket, buffer, 256, 0); // receive data

fwrite(buffer, sizeof(char), file_block_size, fr); // write data into the file
```

Surely the number of bytes you write should be the number of bytes you read (which you helpfully stored in a variable, `data`, but didn't use), not some other number.

If you really want to make HTTP 1.1 client and server code, you really should start by thoroughly understanding both the HTTP 1.1 specification and example client and server code. But that's a *terrible* way to learn how to send and receive files because HTTP 1.1 is so complicated.

Comment: Yes I know there was supposed to be data, not the file block size. I my bad while writing the question : ) .

Comment: You need to actually implement the HTTP protocol. You faked it on the sending end, sort of. But you didn't even fake it on the receiving end. You need to write a parser or protocol engine. Have a look at existing ones to see what they typically look like.